# Easyphp development environment aliases not working

Tags: apache, easyphp

I use Easyphp for my development environment on my Windows PC and Laptop. For some odd reason I am unable to get aliasing to work on my laptop. I get an error:

```
Object not found!
```

I think it is a problem with Apache, but I am unsure. It is probably something dead simple, but I have spent way to many hours trying to work it out for myself. I have tried to manually write the alias and I have tried reinstalling easyphp, but I can't get it to work. Could the default virtual host be interfering with the alias?

Here is what is at the bottom of the httpd.conf file:

```
# == !!! DO NOT REMOVE !!! ===================================================
### Alias EasyPHP
# ============================================================================
#alias
Alias "/development" "C:/Users/Sam/dev"
<Directory "C:/Users/Sam/dev">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Deny from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
#alias
# ============================================================================
### Alias End
# ============================================================================


# == !!! DO NOT REMOVE !!! ===================================================
### VirtualHost EasyPHP
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-12.1/www"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
# ============================================================================
#virtualhost
#virtualhost
# ============================================================================
### VirtualHost End
# ============================================================================
```

Answer (score 2):

@Sam: I'm no guru, but have just solved this for myself and thought I'd share my experience. I have happily used EasyPHP 12.1 for several weeks, adding and deleting aliases through testing various WordPress setups. Suddenly, aliases I added threw up the "Object not found" error, no matter how I addressed them. I checked my httpd.conf file and found the recently added aliases were not present (?). Manually adding the ones I needed (and deleting the obsolete ones) solved it for me.
Note: my httpd.conf file ends with my last alias, and not with a "virtualhost" entry:

...

```
Alias "/mangala" "C:/_localwebs/mangala"
<Directory "C:/_localwebs/mangala">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Deny from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
Alias "/zenphoto" "C:/_localwebs/zenphoto"
<Directory "C:/_localwebs/zenphoto">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Deny from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
#alias
# ========================
# ========================
```

Hope you've either sorted it already, or this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately my solution was to download xampp.

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if you have Apache and mysql started as a service, becuase I had this problem and Apache being started as a service is what was the problem for me.